# Submitting POST form data in UTF -8

Tags: java, html

I have a form in which the user enters his name in Chinese, but when I do

```
String strName = request.getParameter("name");
```

I get strName as some meaningless characters. As a solution I tried

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

before reading any parameters from the request object. **This worked**. What I want to know is how do I achieve this in **HTML/javascript** . I have tried the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but this doesn't work . Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you define the charset in the `Content-Type` request header. I believe it is usually not defined by default. For example if you use jQuery to make the request you have to add "charset=utf-8" to the `contentType` option: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

There's no way to force a web browser to send Content-Type for every request, so it's better call `setCharacterEncoding` always.

Answer (score 0):

What you do client-side affects how the data is sent. Apparently the data *is* sent as UTF-8 encoded, since the problem was in *reading* it server-side. So adding the `meta` (though OK) has no effect on this.

Answer (score 0):

In pure HTML you should need `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">` set to submit utf-8 in the browser.

Comment: It is not needed if the document’s own encoding is UTF-8, as it apparently is here, since the data is sent as UTF-8. And it does not by any means make it unnecessary to make sure that the server-side code processes the data as UTF-8.